# How to update a file inside a jar directory

Tags: java, jar

I have seen similar answers but none of them helped me so far. I want to know if there is any command to update a class file inside a Jar directory.

I have this Jar:

```
META-INF/
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
src/
src/project/
....
src/project/dir/Myfile.class
META-INF/dir/
etc..
```

I have modified Myfile.class and I want to update the existing inside the jar's directory.

I tried

```
jar uf myJar.jar -C src/project/dir Myfile.class
```

but it does not work as expected. The jar is still the same.

Any ideas?

Edit: Working on cmd

Comment: you can easily update the jar with WINRAR or other zip utilities.

Answer (score 3):

```
jar uf myJar.jar -C src/project/dir Myfile.class
```

will place Myfile.class in the root of the jar. Instead, do

```
jar uf myJar.jar src/project/dir/Myfile.class
```

Comment: Does not find the file... It gives no such file or directory

Comment: Tina, is src/ in the same directory as myJar.jar?

Comment: src is the directory inside the jar...

Comment: src/ must also be a directory outside the jar for what you are doing. If you use the -C flag, it should specify the directory that contains the src/ directory.